# How to interpolate a multidimensional xarray?

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, netcdf

I read a `netCDF` file using `xarray`. The dataset contains `lat`, `lon` information of the `population` for the years: 1975, 1990, 2000 and 2015.

The dataset looks like the following and I made it also available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RaCFzlXi2vAkdhQPR4G95Vzm67JaUOY5/view?usp=sharing):

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('borneo_pop_t.nc')
ds
```

[image]

For each pixel I would like to have the information of each year between 1975 and 2000 given the trend of the data points I have. In particular I would like to generate more information and different layers of the population for the missing years.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xarray`'s interpolation [function](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/interpolation.html).

Using your variable names,

```
import pandas as pd

# Create time series of 1x a year data
# (you can use any date range; you can generate pretty much 
# any sequence you need with pd.date_range()) 
dates = pd.date_range('1975-01-01','2015-01-01',freq='1Y') 

# Linear interpolation
ds_interp = ds.interp(time=dates)
```

Note a few things:

1. This code just generates a simple linear interpolation, though `ds.interp()` supports everything that `scipy.interpolate.interp1d()` does - e.g., cubic, polynomial, etc. interpolation. Check the docks linked above for examples.
2. This of course doesn't *create* new information; you still only "know" the population at the original points. Be wary what consequences interpolating the data will have on your understanding of what the population actually was in a given year.